# Calculate the Path Sum in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

Trying to calculate the path sum to the leaf from the root in a binary tree. Doesn't seem to be working, the value for doesIt becomes true, but since it's recursion it switches back to false as the stack pops. Not sure how to fix it. **How do I change my code so that once the value for doesIt changes to true it propagates all the way up the stack?**

Consider tree : [5,4,8,11,null,null,null,7,2] **InOrder**

so 5 has two children 4 and 8, 4 has 1 child 11, 8 has no children

hasPathSum(root,22)

```
public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    boolean doesIt = false;
    if (root != null)
    {
        doesIt = pathSum(root, sum, 0, doesIt);
    }
    return doesIt;
}

private static boolean pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum, int sumSoFar, boolean doesIt)
{
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
    {
        if (sumSoFar+root.val == sum)
        {
            doesIt = true;
            return doesIt;
        }
        return doesIt;
    }

    if (root.left != null)
    {
        pathSum(root.left, sum, sumSoFar+root.val,doesIt);
    }

    if (root.right != null)
    {
        pathSum(root.right, sum, sumSoFar+root.val,doesIt);
    }

    return doesIt;
}
```

Comment: what about the 7 and 2.Draw a tree and update answer.

Comment: When `pathSum` calls itself recursively, the inner `pathSum` calls return a value, but you don't use it.  You just need to fix your method so that it uses those return values.  I don't know how, though, since I don't understand what the method is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You just throwing the value given by calling method on children. I slightly rewrite your code to this:

```
private static boolean pathSum(TreeNode root, final int sum, int sumSoFar) {
    if (root == null) return false;
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) return sumSoFar + root.val == sum;
    return pathSum(root.left, sum, sumSoFar + root.val) || pathSum(root.right, sum, sumSoFar + root.val);
}
```

It's basic recursion: for `null` node answer is false by definition, leaf is another corner case, general case trying to achieve success in one of the two branches.

P.S. It's not very clear from question and method signature what are you trying to achieve, but I suppose that you check whether there is a path from the root to the any leaf with the given `sum` path sum